# MS Access query Comparing Number and Display

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

```
SELECT Student_Number,
DATEPART("yyyy", Starting_Date) AS Starting_Year,
DATEPART("yyyy",Ending_Date) AS Ending_Year
FROM   PGME
WHERE  ID = 1
```

Display as below

```
Student_Number    Starting_Year Ending_Year
003329497         1994          1999
```

But what I need is comparing the "Starting_Year" and "Ending_Year" (**they are randomly date**), when "Ending_Year" is bigger than "Starting_Year", it will display a new row until it the "Starting_Year" is equal to "Ending_Year". (I am expecting to get the following result)

```
Student_Number    Starting_Year Ending_Year
003329497         1994          1999
003329497         1995          1999
003329497         1996          1999
003329497         1997          1999
003329497         1998          1999
003329497         1999          1999
```

Student_Number(1)

```
Student_Number    Starting_Year Ending_Year
002442895         1993          2000
002442895         1994          2000
002442895         1995          2000
002442895         1996          2000
002442895         1997          2000
002442895         1998          2000
002442895         1999          2000
002442895         2000          2000
```

Student_Number(2)

There are more than 100 "Student_Number" I need to do with. I am thinking using "if" statement to do it, but can not figure it out. Any ways to do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Cartesian (multiplying) query:

```
SELECT 
    Student_Number,
    Year(Starting_Date) + Ten.N AS Starting_Year,
    Year(Ending_Date) AS Ending_Year
FROM
    PGME,
        (SELECT DISTINCT Abs([id] Mod 10) AS N
        FROM msysobjects) As Ten
WHERE
    PGME.ID = 1
    And
    Ten.N <= Year(Ending_Date) - Year(Starting_Date)
```

Comment: It works! Thank you!

how can I display the rest of Student_Number? using ID = 2? But I have to edit them one by one.
any ways to print the Student_Number(1) in sheet one, and the Student_Number(2) in sheet two, up to the end of Student_Number

Comment: If you remove the criterium for the ID, you will get them all. Or pass the ID as a parameter for individual selection.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I try to remove the criterium, but it comes up the random number. How can I pass the ID as a parameter? to combine all the data as one table. Thank you again.

Comment: You can insert a parameter: `PGME.ID = [PgmeID]` and then supply that when needed.